# How can I set up alerts to notify me of COVID-19 clinical trial participation opportunities for healthy US volunteers outside of infection “hotspots”?

Tags: research, clinical-study, coronavirus

I live in a mid-size US city not hit too hard by the coronavirus. Is there a good way to set up email alerts (or similar) to alert me to COVID-19 clinical trials in my area that I can volunteer for? I ask because I've heard that [there may soon be trials](https://www.nature.com/articles/d41586-020-00927-3) recruiting uninfected individuals.

The best method I have found so far is to set up an RSS feed at clinicaltrials.gov.

Thanks!

Comment: Not too hard is just a question of time unfortunately

Comment: Just a question of time to set up email alerts?

Comment: Your city will also be hit hard eventually unless you lock it down

Comment: Alas, very true.

Comment: That live challenge thing was one academic proposal. Not taken up the gov't as far as I know. And they need to approve the trials.